# Can VBA in excel run multiple timers concurrently

Tags: excel, vba

I have a timing program on a userform that has 5 moving graphics. The graphics are animated by repositioning one image overlayed over a second image using

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Dim StopCode As Boolean
Dim EndTick As Date

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Call ThirdLevel
    
End Sub

Sub ThirdLevel()

    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim sngPercent As Single
    Dim sngPercent2 As Single
    Dim intMax As Integer
    Dim intRepeat As Integer
    
    StopCode = False
    intMax = 100
    
        For intRepeat = 1 To 100
            Do While True
                If StopCode Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                For intIndex = 1 To intMax
                    sngPercent = intIndex / intMax
                    sngPercent2 = (100 - intIndex) / 100
                    BeltMover sngPercent, sngPercent2
                    DoEvents
                    Sleep 1
                Next
            Loop
        Next
End Sub
```

My issue is that each of the 5 animations has a user defined delay to allow them to run at different speeds. This is accomplished by the user selecting from a set of predetermined speed setting in the form of option buttons. There are 5 groups of option buttons, one set for each animation. The 5 graphics run independent from each other and at different speeds but are connected in precedence. Graphic 2 can not run unless graphic 1 is running, graphic 3 can not run unless graphic 2 is running, etc. If graphic 1 stops all other graphics stop, if graphic 2 stops graphic 3-5 stop but graphic 1 still runs, etc. I need to be able to monitor and record how much time elapses as each graphic is running and how much time elapses while each graphic is stopped. To accomplish this I need to have 5 separate timers all running concurrently so that I can record the start and stop times. I do not have any sample code to show as I have tried many version of coding with zero success and after extensive googling I think I am asking more than excel VBA can do. Does anyone know of a way to run 5 concurrent timers that are independent of each other?

I forgot to add that I have already tried using nested IFs, Do While, Select Case, Do Loop scenarios but have run into the issue that the animation do not update correctly. When stepping through the code line by line the graphics work fine but just running the code causes the animations to erratically work and not work. I believe this issue is caused do to the fact that since all the timing is in seconds the Now() time ellipses the momentary start/stop segments before the graphic has time to update. That is why I am trying to create 5 separate timers.

Comment: IMO you are using the wrong tool for the job. Excel is not meant for things like this.

Comment: I am limited to the MS Office programs to accomplish this feat. Do you have any other suggestion then. I have already tried PowerPoint with no success.

Comment: None of the office apps are going to be a good choice. Why would you have such a limitation?

Comment: Security limitation at my work. I was given an exception to enable macros / VBA but nothing else.

Comment: You may want to explain this to your employer then.

Comment: I was afraid I had hit a road block. That you for the help.

Comment: FWIW: This seems like something Powerpoint MIGHT be able to do, but not using `Timer` objects. If you can create something manually in Powerpoint that works, you can then record a macro while you set it up again, and it should give you some ideas on how it's done in VBA.

Comment: https://www.vishalon.net/blog/2-ways-to-add-custom-path-animation-effect-using-vba-in-powerpoint-2013

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.motioneffect